# Exporting and importing const in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to hold a const value so it could be used in other components. In this example, i want to for example be able to hold `const age` from Form.jsx to be rendered in App.js using {age}.

I have excluded the import files for shortening the code, but here's is my example

**Form.jsx**

```
  function Form() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(0);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl>
        <Select value={age} onChange={handleChange}>
          <MenuItem value={0}>None</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {

  
  return (
    <div>
      <Form />
      <p>{age}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I would have choose menuItem with a value of 20, the function App would have rendered `<p>20</p>`.
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this will a callback in `<App />` but I believe it is best practice to have the parent be the "single source of truth" when it comes to state.

(more reading & code: https://webomnizz.com/change-parent-component-state-from-child-using-hooks-in-react/)

```
function Form(props) {
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        // Here, we invoke the callback with the new value
        props.onChange(event.target.value);
    }
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl>
        <Select value={props.age} onChange={handleChange}>
          <MenuItem value={0}>None</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

```
function App() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(0);
  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setAge(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form age={age} onChange={handleChange}  />
      <p>{age}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I can see two options at a glance:

- You can lift the state one level up

So `age` would be a variable in `App` component and you can update it every time `Form` component gets modified. Something like this:

```
  function Form({age, setAge}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl>
        <Select value={age} onChange={(event) => setAge(event.target.value)}>
          <MenuItem value={0}>None</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

```
function App() {

  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(0);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Form age={age} setAge={setAge} />
      <p>{age}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

With the above setup, `age` is available in both `App` component and `Form` component and both of them will be synchronized.

- You can use a state library (like [redux](https://redux.js.org/)) to create a global store and use it distribute `age` variable to anywhere you want in your application, not just the `App` component. But this is way overkill for the above scenario and I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data in this way from child to parent component because the created variable is not in the scope of the `App.js` component. For passing data from child to parent component, create the state variable in the parent component `App.js` and pass the event handler function which sets the value to the child component.

**App.jsx**

```
function App() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(0)

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Age:{age}</h2>
      <Form age={age} handleChange={handleChange}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Form.jsx**

```
  function Form({age, handleChange}) {

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl>
        <Select value={age} onChange={handleChange}>
          <MenuItem value={0}>None</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

here is the similar working example:- https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-night-zfsig

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for posting your solutions. But as I mentioned in the post description, I want {age} to be used in other components, by that I mean every components. Lets say I have `const sumAge = ({age} + {age})`, will sumAge be reachable in other components now?